# What does dot notation for classes, properties and methods mean?

Tags: matlab, class, oop

I'm a relative newbie to programming, except having used basic capabilities of Matlab for several years (manipulating arrays, linear algebra, functions, scripts, etc.) and am very recently starting to explore the object oriented side of the program (which is also my first foray into *any* object oriented programming!).

My biggest sticking point right now is understanding what the heck this dot notation means. For example, say I write the simple class

```
classdef alchemy
    properties
        element
    end

    methods
%   CONSTRUCTOR
        function e = alchemy
            e.element = '    ';
        end
    end
end
```

What does the `e.element` actually mean? Then typing into the command line

```
e.element = 'LEAD'
```

assigns the string `'LEAD'` to one instance of the property `element` of the class `alchemy`.... Why does it do this?

Now say I add the method

```
        function e = transmute(e)
            oldElem = e.element;
            if oldElem == 'LEAD'
                e = 'GOLD';
            elseif oldElem == 'GOLD'
                e = 'LEAD';
            else
                disp('Oh no! This is a non-transmutable element.');
            end
        end
```

I can now put in the command line `e = e.transmute` and it will return

```
e =

GOLD
```

What is going on in *this* situation with the dot notation? Why does `e.transumte` apply the function `transmute` to `e`? I'm really confused by this whole notation, and none of Matlab's help-pages give me any deeper inkling. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot notation is used for a property/attribute of the object or for invoking a method.

It has both meanings.

```
 name_object.abc
```

will give you the value of abc if abc is a property of name_object, or will invoke abc on name_object if abc it's a method.

Comment: Very clear. Actually that makes a lot more sense now! (Why don't they have such a simple explanation in the mathworks pages...?)

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/matlab-operators-and-special-characters.html#bvg3oy_-5) *does* have this explanation for `.`

Answer (score 1):

The class (or object) in Matlab is a collection of `properties` and `methods`.

Maybe what is confusing is that your method `transmute` accepts the object (it should) but returns a string with the same variable name as the original object. It is more or less a "get value of" method. Not a transmute object.

In this way it returns the transmuted object.

```
function e = transmute(e)
    switch e.element 
        case 'LEAD'
            e.element = 'GOLD';
        case 'GOLD'
            e.element = 'LEAD';
        otherwise
            disp('Oh no! This is a non-transmutable element.');
    end
end
```

You can also call the method like this:

```
e = transmute(e)
```

It is equal to

```
e = e.transmute
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! Does `switch` only work in a method?

Also I didn't really understand your second paragraph. What do you mean by "`transmute`accepts the object"? And then by "It is [...] a 'get value of' method."? The way I had written it initially produces exactly the same results as your re-writing of it.

Comment: No. `switch` is just normal matlab. You have a method called `transmute`. On the right hand side, the input, it accepts e. This is your object. On the left hand side, the output, it outputs something called e. In your case it is a string, in my case it is the object. (In your case, when it is not transmutable, it returns the object.)