# How can Powershell compare between string and double?

Tags: powershell

I just realized that PowerShell can compare between string and number, I don't understand this because they are different types. How can PowerShell compare them?

```
PS C:\> Get-Host | Select-Object Version

Version
-------
5.1.19041.1023


PS C:\> $version = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | where name -eq 'AWS Command Line Interface v2').Version
PS C:\> $version
2.0.7.0
PS C:\> $version -is [string]
True
PS C:\> 2.0 -is [double]
True
PS C:\> $version -gt 2.0
True
PS C:\> $version -gt 2.1
False
PS C:\> $version -gt 2.0.9
True
```

Comment: It's not converting to double, it's converting to string and doing a string comparison like `'b' -gt 'a or whatever'`. `2.0.9 -is [double]` is returning a string too

Comment: @Daniel Please don't just throw a link, I know how to convert them. Could you please explain the mechanism?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers of course 2.0.9 is not double, no number has 2 dots in decimal.

Comment: I know, it wasn't obvious you knew.  It's just string comparison.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers If it is string comparison, why ```$version -eq 2.0.7.0``` returns False. (same version)

Comment: Now *that* is a good question. No idea as of yet.

Comment: `$Null -eq 2.0.9` ==> True

Comment: @iRon - so 2.1 is converted from double to string but 2.0.9 is $null? I'm having a hard time seeing the logic behind the implicit type conversions here. All academic as you should use the proper types to begin with as per your answer but gtk nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, that is apparently the case (I have no explanation yet).

Comment: Both `$version -gt 2.0.9` and `$version -gt 2.0.6` return true. It's indeed just comparing to $null and not to string as I would have expected.

Comment: I have created a new PowerShell request for this: [`#15756` Unquoted numbers with two or more dots should cast to a `[version]` rather then`$Null`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15756)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

... and you probably don't want to use either of these types,
but use the [`[Version]` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.version) type instead:

```
$version = [Version]'2.0.7.0'
$version -gt [Version]'2.0'
True
$version -gt [Version]'2.1'
False
$version -gt [Version]'2.0.9'
False
```

**For what you tried:**

As you noted yourself, the `version` property of the `WMI` query returns a `[String]` type and numbers with a (single) dot automatically cast to a `[Double]`. Knowing that the type at the LHS (left hand side) of the operator dictates the comparison type, all the concerned comparison examples in the question are string comparisons. Meaning:

```
'2.0.7.0' -gt '2.0'
True
'2.0.7.0' -gt '2.1'
False
```

The unexpected thing though, is that an (unquoted) number with 2 or more dots returns a `$Null`:

```
$Null -eq 2.0.9
True
```

Which will be cased to an empty string in the following comparison:

```
'2.0.7.0' -gt 2.0.9 # --> '2.0.7.0' -gt $Null --> '2.0.7.0' -gt ''
True
```

<sub>I have created a new PowerShell request for this issue:

[`#15756` Unquoted numbers with two or more dots should cast to a `[version]` rather then `$Null`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15756)</sub>

---

**Addendum**
The explanation why a number with 2 or more dots doesn't generate an (syntax) error is covered in the response of the related [`#15756` request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15756).

In fact only the first dot is a interpreted as a [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator), the rest of the dots are presumed [member (property/method) separators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48926006/1701026).
By default, PowerShell is not a strict language. This implies that if you references to non-existent properties of any object type (including strings and even [primitives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type)), it just returns `$Null`.

Huh???, I can understand that a primitive has methods like `2.0.ToInt32($Null)` but how could a primitive as a `double` have a (custom) property as e.g. `9`?
In PowerShell, it is possible to "*decorate*" (add a property to) any object using the [`Add-Member` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member):

```
$Version = 2.0 |Add-Member 9 'Nine' -PassThru
$Version |ConvertTo-Json
{
  "value": 2.0,
  "9": "Nine"
}
$Version -is [Double]
True
$Version.9
Nine
```

To force an error if you reference a non-existent property, you might use the [`Set-StrictMode` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode):

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
2.0.9 # Similar to e.g.: $Version.0
```

> `PropertyNotFoundException: The property '9' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.`